# Angular: API returns a request of 204 NO CONTENT, how do I take a user back to a different page?

Tags: angular, typescript

Right now I have an API working on a returned String, however if there is no string, I need to return them back to a different page but not sure how to do this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.appService.showLoader(true);
    this.coachService.GetCategories().subscribe(res =>
     {
      this.appService.showLoader(false);
      if (res && res.length === null){
          this.router.navigate([appRoutesNames.COACH_INTERACTION, coachInteractionRouteNames.CREATE_SESSION ])
          this.appService.openSnackBar('You do not have access to this Service');
          
          } else if (res && res.length === 1) {
              if(res[0].name === 'Mindset'){
                this.disabled = false;
                localStorage.setItem(localKeys.SELECTED_SESSION_TYPE, SupportAreaCategory.Mindset.toString());
                this.coachService.storeMatchMakerPayload(SupportAreaCategory.Mindset, 'CategoryId');
                this.router.navigate([appRoutesNames.COACH_INTERACTION, coachInteractionRouteNames.MATCH_MAKING, coachMatchMakingRouteNames.MINDSET])             }
```

When the String at res[0].name is matched, that now takes them to the right page, but its the part where no string is that I'm struggling with, I've tried:

```
 if (res && res.length === null)
```

&

```
if (res && res.length === 0)
```

but both give the same result and do nothing on the page (including giving the snackbar message)

Comment: Could it be that the variable ```res``` is null?

What if you change ```if (res && res.length === null)``` to ```if (!res)```?

Comment: Oh of course, yes it !res then do this, yes res was NULL, this seems to have worked! Thank you